# Can I detect that javascript is being loaded unminified (as debug mode)

Tags: javascript, debugging, detection, bundling-and-minification

I would like to provide additional console logs when I'm running my app in *debug mode* (unminified and unbundled scripts). Is there an easy way to detect this in a script?

I was thinking of having a function with a long parameter name and then get a string representation of that function checking whether that parameter has this long name or was it changed to shorter version during minification (because minifiers do that).

**Is there a better, simpler way?**

I would like to avoid a situation where I would have a global variable set to a specific value and then forget to reset it during deployment. I want something bullet proof that eliminates human error.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have any built-in notion of minification, and there's no standard for how it's done. So the only generic solution I can think of is the one you described, where you test the string representation of the function.

Comment: I agree, testing the string representation would be the best way to do this (and perhaps only way I can think of indirectly).

Comment: In this case you're talking about minified files that you have created? Or third party libraries also?

Comment: @jwatts1980 third party libs as well. I know that not all minify parameter names... but I can live with that because Asp.net B&M does change those as well as many others do too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Minification detection

As mentioned in the question, this is the solution I've been thinking about and does the job just fine. As long as minification algorithm also minifies function names and parameters, this detection will work as expected.

```
window.debugging = (function detect(undefined) {
    // has function itself been renamed?
    if (!detect) return false;
    // has parameter been renamed?
    return /function\s\w+\((\w*)\)/i.exec(detect.toString())[1] === "undefined";
})();
```

and they have functions that are used within code like:

```
var debuglog = (function() {
    if (debugging === true)
    {
        return console.log;
    }
    return function() { return; };
})();
```

if that's just one function it can as well we incorporated in the original detection function so instead of returning true/false it would return a `console.log` redirection function or no-op function.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of checking the length of a bit of source code would work.

But, a more conventional approach would be to externalize your global variables / environment configuration as a separate file that you include during dev/production:

- env.js (used for production)
- env.dev.js (used in development)

In development, your application would by default include env.dev.js. During minification for production, you would include env.js instead.